# Line distortions in tiles generated with gdal2tiles

Tags: gdal2tiles

**Objective**: generate mercator tiles 256x256 from a huge jpeg2000 image.
**Tool used**: gdal2tiles.py
**GDAL version**: 3.2.2
**Command line**: gdal2tiles.py -z 19 -r [any] image.jp2 tiles/

**Source image**: image.jp2 is in CRS Lambert93 (2154), coming from IGN ORTHO-HR open database (resolution 20 cm per pixel) https://geoservices.ign.fr/documentation/diffusion/telechargement-donnees-libres.html#ortho-irc50cm-et-hr

**Problem**: there are some distortions in all tiles generated, visible on road or building edges (as shown in illustration). The distortion doesn't depend on the resampling method used.

**Illustration**:
[image]

The samples are 256x256 pixels tiles, generated with gdal2tiles, with different -r options. 1_original.png is an extract (done with QGIS) from jp2 original image, for the same area as the tile.

The source CRS is well defined in source image metadata, so I don't use -s option on command line to specify it (I tried, but it doesn't change anything as expected).

Comment: Maybe the change of CRS (Lamber93 to 3857) introduces some distortions...

Comment: Is there a way to avoid these distorsions?

Comment: Some interpolation methods are better/worst than others. (sorry, I can't give you a definitive solution)

Comment: If you mean -r option of gdal2tiles, I tried all of them without any influence on the artefact (as it can be seen in the illustration)

Comment: Try `gdalwarp -of VRT -t_srs epsg:3857 image.jp2 image.vrt` and run gdal2tiles on that vrt file. Probably there is no difference. What JPEG2000 driver do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user30184, I got better results using gdalwarp before gdal2tiles:

**Step 1:**

```
gdalwarp -of VRT -s_srs EPSG:2154 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r average -srcnodata "255 255 255" -dstnodata "255 255 255" image.jp2 image.vrt
```

**Step 2:**

```
gdal2tiles.py -z 19 -r average image.vrt ./tiles
```

New result obtained for the sample tile:
[image]

*Remaining question: is there a need to use a second time -r average in gdal2tiles command, as resampling should have been done by gdalwarp?*